# How to use git templates in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am trying to use Git Templates in Visual Studio 2022 but I can't find any post related to this.
I configured a global template on git.
Now I would like to get the commit message on my solution which contains 6 repositories (I can commit all of them with the multi repository support in Visual Studio 2022).

I have also Git Extensions Tool and there it works. I would like to do it from Visual Studio.

I tried to find some plugin because Visual Studio doesn't support this feature.